# big query table functions parameters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is this supported in bigquery

```
select a
from table_with_parameters AS t
JOIN my_table_fuction(t.par1, t.par2, t.par3) AS u
```

I keep getting undetified identifier "t" on line 3...

Comment: To use [JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join_types) you need to follow this sitnaxis "select * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.w = B.y"

Comment: it is not supported the way you have it in the question. but there is an easy workaround  - just provide more details on your use case so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you have it, you need to add in the columns you need into the SELECT statement, an example would be

```
SELECT 
a,
t.par1,
t.par2,
t.par3

FROM table_with_parameters 
INNER JOIN my_table_fuction AS t
```

Its hard to say with the example you've provided though.